# Image transformation by clustering

Tags: image-processing, opencv, cluster-analysis

I am doing a project on image binarisation where I am required to transform an image such that its divided into individual color layers using clustering. What I mean to say is that there will be no shades in the image, instead the shades of the input image will be converted into a layer dividing the two colors.

The input and output images are given:[image]

I am trying to implement this using opencv, but not able to figure out how to do that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using k-means clustering.
http://aishack.in/tutorials/kmeans-clustering-opencv/

You get as many colours as you have means.

Here is an example being implemented using the Accord.NET C# library.
http://crsouza.blogspot.com.au/2010/10/k-means-clustering.html